# Enable Live Graph in Memory Usage while Debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cpu-usage, visual-studio-debugging, debug-diagnostic-tool

Somehow I have lost the live graph from my Visual Studio Diagnostic Tool.
Below is my current debugging screen showing that I can not see Memory and CPU usage live graph :

[image]

[image]

Where as I am looking for this :

[image]

I tried exploring in following places as well online :

1. Debug > Profiler > Performance Explorer
2. Tools > Options > Debugging
3. Tools > Options > IntelliTrace

Does anybody know how to enable Memory and CPU Usage live graph ?

Comment: I have the same problem, live graph was working fine but is now gone. Did you find a way to bring it back?

Comment: Nope, I have changed some settings which I am not willing to undo in my project which caused this. So I ended up using diagnostic session starting them manually using profiling tools.

Comment: For future visitors: see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39568058/429949) by Jesper. Basically, the tab pane gets scrolled all the way to the top and you need to grab the gray bar just below the header and drag it down.

Answer (score 67):

There is a ruler you can drag down, above the Events, Memory Usage and CPU Usage Tab, where the live graph was hidden.

Comment: Wow! This was definitely the issue for me. What an oddity.

Comment: whoah, that one's a doozy. thanks. I wonder how many easter eggs they're hiding like that

Comment: Thanks this was my issue.

Comment: @RahulMakwana You do have it.  It's the gray bar right under the blue bar at the top of your screen capture.

Comment: when I take my cursor over at the edge between "Events", "Memory Usage","CPU Usage" Tabs and Diagnostic Tools Header, cursor doesn't change. I can not drag it below like others mentioned. I did do enough efforts before I posted this question, thanks!

Comment: Can't believe this was my issue. How embarrassing.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem and found out that cursor changes on narrow gray line just below window header. Try to click and drag it down. It's hard to notice on bright theme so it may even be harder on dark one.
I hope it will help you.

This narrow line hides graph:

[image]

Comment: The question was:
Does anybody know how to enable Memory and CPU Usage live graph ?


Looking at screenshot added in one of responses his graph was dragged up. So it do answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

If your Diagnostic Tools Window is closed, you can reopen it by `Debug > Windows > Show Diagnostic Tools` **(Ctrl + Alt + F2)**

Comment: No as you can see Diagnostic Tools window was still there, its just the graph which was missing fro window

Answer (score 0):

Like this blog here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/13/memory-usage-tool-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015/

and a MSDN document:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125494.aspx

Whenever you want to capture the state of memory, choose "Take snapshot" on the Memory Usage summary toolbar.

For CPU Usage, you need to enable it and then debug it for the next time after a debugger breakpoint was hit.

For example, if I debug an UWP app for the first time, I will got a messages "Enable CPU profiling to see a breakdown of CPU usage by function" under the CPU Usage window, I will click it, and then debug the app for the next time, I will get the CPU Usage.
[image]

Comment: I see your point sir,I did try that before posting this question but it wasn't much of a help. What I want is, regardless of any breakpoint hit, it used to show me Live Graph of memory, CPU usage. All of sudden due to "some" change it has stopped displaying it.

Comment: If it worked well before, I suggest you reset VS settings.

Comment: No help even after re-installing VS. Guess it has something to do with my Project Configurations

Comment: How about creating a new simple app? For example, just create a blank UWP app, how about the result if you debug it?

Comment: I do have another project I am working on, it works just fine on it.

Comment: If so, we would think about the project itself. Whether it is the same project type? Create a blank solution, and then add all project file to this new blank solution, clean and build solution, test it again. Please also compare the .xxproj file and find the differences.

Answer (score 0):

As Rahul notes, the answer in the blog does not directly fix the issue. I have the same issue and what I've observed is that if you add the existing project to a new solution file, then the real time graphs come back. This isn't quite ideal, but it does provide a work around.

Comment: I agree that new solution file will do the job because few configurations(which I don't know what was the trigger) I have done with my existing solution will no more in effect.